# Master project: Video processing and data science: Finding a pattern on a dataframe of video

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-science

I am a master student (in applied maths) and in one year I will start my master project (which I am willing to continue in a phd thesis).
The question is about the feasibility of my project and how can I improve/modify it !
My project is about sport videos (example: freestyle snowboard).
There are a lot of Professional snowboarders that upload their tricks on the internet (which constitute a huge data basis) and what I want to do is to collect all the videos (I guess it won't be a problem) and try to find a pattern of the tricks (the figure made by the riders). By 'analyse them', I mean create a kind of artificial intelligence that first recognize the trick (I will construct a model for each trick) and then try to give advise on how to improve the trick (by analysing the position you have before the jump and the position of your body in the air).
This AI could be useful for judges in contest and for learning snowboarders.
I tried to imagine how to do it even if I do not have finish my master so this is why I am asking the question here: Is it a totally impossible algorithm (because of the time it would require or else) ? Should I focus on one part of this project (I guess that this project will mix différent topics maybe I should just do one step of my project).

Sorry for the long post, I thank you to read this unusual question and I hope someone will have the answer to my problem.

Comment: This is too broad for SO and sounds more like a problem for full-research team (and even then the time horizon is hard). Analyzing videos to recognize tricks might be possible, although surely not trivial. But steps toward improvement will contain extra research topics like bio-mechanics (including a body-model of all those joints) and physics.

Answer (score 0):

In a broader perspective, you might want to use video intelligence. A video is just a  number of frames or images. These images could be feed to a Convolutional neural network. But the network needs to remember what it saw in the earlier frame. So you need to use Recurrent neural network.

> A hybrid of the above networks will be a  Deep Convolutional Recurrent neural network.

1. Place some Conv2D layers and input them some frames of the video.
2. Add LSTM layers.
3. Add Dense layers and the output layer.